# No spatial operator found joining non postgis table

Tags: postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis, spatial

I'm trying to join two tables in the same database but different schemas.

One has a PostGis geometry column and the other only 'x' and 'y' utm coordinates.

My knowledge about GIS and spatial databases is almost none but, googling and checking documentation I've been able to check if those coordinates are in given geometry but **when I try to join the tables by this criteria it throws following error:

```
ERROR:  no spatial operator found for 'st_contains': opfamily 192287 type 192174
```

The whole query is as follows:

```
select z.nom                                                                
from geogps."ZonesConfinament" as z                                         
join ecadma.isr as isr on (                                                 
    geogps.ST_Contains(                                                     
        z.geom                                                              
        , geogps.ST_SetSRID(                                                
            geogps.ST_MakePor just change the condition to isContained = falseoint(isr.longitude, isr.latitude),               
            25831                                                           
        )                                                                   
    )
```

or just change the condition to `isContained = false`

```
);                                                                          
-- ERROR:  no spatial operator found for 'st_contains': opfamily 192287 type 192174
```

Not sure if I'm doing the conversion right (I know our UTM coordinates are in 31N zone but I don't know where I can specify that). But what makes me stuck is the fact I can get that value (no -yet- matter if it's correct or not) in the projection of a whole cross join but it does not work in the selection.

Consider following query:

```
with isrjoin as (                                                               
    select                                                                      
        z.nom                                                                   
        , geogps.ST_Contains(                                                   
            z.geom                                                              
            , geogps.ST_SetSRID(                                                
                geogps.ST_MakePoint(isr.longitude, isr.latitude),               
                25831                                                           
            )                                                                   
        ) as isContained                                                        
    from geogps."ZonesConfinament" as z                                         
    cross join ecadma.isr                                                       
)                                                                               
select *                                                                        
from isrjoin                                                                    
where isContained                                                               
limit 10                                                                        
;        

                                                                   If I change condition to `isContained = false` or just remove the 'where' clause (or even executing only *isrjoin* CTE contents), it works (I get 10 rows with the `limit 10`).
```

**But** when I try to change that condition as is shown before, I get that *No spatial operator found* error.

I checked for nulls in *x* and *y* columns, but there are none.

There are '0's thought, but:

```
select geogps.ST_SetSRID(                                                   
    geogps.ST_MakePoint(0, 0)                                               
    , 25831                                                                 
);                                                                          
                    st_setsrid                                              
----------------------------------------------------                        
0101000020E764000000000000000000000000000000000000                          
(1 row)
```

Anyway, as far as I know, CTE is selecting all rows so, despite if that conversion works for every row or not, it should have thrown either if I finally try to select those columns or not.

From my PostgreSQL background knowledge it looks illogical to me (I've avoided errors errors by pre-discarding non interesting problematic columns several times before. But now that strategy seems to not work and I don't understand why).

> **FINAL NOTE:** Just now I've tried to:
>
> ```
> set search_path=geogps,ecadma;
> ```
>
> It's my fault not having done this before (PostGis objects are in
> geogps and I'm building the queries using postgresql user -I usually
> make queries work first and then bother assigning permissions to the
> user that will use it in production-. This is why I always prefix
> tables with schema name).
>
> BUT **I still wonder why it works with 'not isContained' and not with
> 'isContained'.

Comment: If setting `search_path` fixes the problem, you should report it as a bug to PostGIS. Support functions shouldn't depend on that setting.

Comment: it is a known issue https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4739

Comment: Thanks to both. Funnily I already planed to have those schemas in default search_path of the user who will execute the query. Just used explit schema addressing to avoid manually setting every time I connect to test with postgres user (to whom I don't want to alter its search_path).

Comment: The query 'set search_path=geogps,ecadma;' works. Thx！